# File Maker Pro 18 (File not found)

Tags: server, filenotfoundexception, filemaker

[Trying to open hosted database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVpZZ.png)

When i am trying to open hosted database from file maker pro 18 it gives me this error.
I have already uploaded the to file maker server

[File uploaded to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSD16.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Complete restart of the server. Also, check if your server licence has expired.

Answer (score 1):

File is not in Open state in Server. Click the downward arrow and click Open.